# Creating GUI with Button to select File Path and Drop Down Selection

Tags: python, user-interface

I am new to creating guis, I am trying to see a way to create a basic gui that allows a user to push a button and it allows them to select pdf file from their machine that way we can set that selection as a file path used later
And have a drop down for the selections 1, 2, 3. And depending on what the selection is it sets that as a variable called pageNum,
those are the only two things needed so once they are both done then they can click Ok to close the gui and have those selections saved and if one of the two were missed then break the code and have then select it when trying to hit Ok

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the File chooser from the library Tkinter for allowing users to select pdf file from their machine

You can see exemple right of this [here](https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/thinkcspy/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html)

Have a nice day